# Using body-parser to get a selected value option

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am new to web programming and I am building an application which got me stuck in one particular part. I am using expressjs and body-parser.
I cannot get a selected value from a select option with body-parser like a text input using req.body.name.

HTML:

```
<form action="/productsAdm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-container">
<select name="condition" name="condicaoProduto" id="condition">
    <option value="novo">Novo</option>
    <option value="usado" selected>Usado</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
```

Backend:

```
app.post("/productsAdm", upload.array("productPictures"), function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.condicaoProduto);
  res.redirect("/productsAdm");
})
```

The reason to be using enctype on the form is that I am also working with file transfer.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `name` attribute of `select` twice
here

```
<select name="condition" name="condicaoProduto" id="condition">
```

You should define

```
<select name="condicaoProduto" id="condition">
```